# Java - в одном методе выбор количества параметров

Tags: java

Класс `Segment`. Есть в нём метод `segmentLenght()`. В методе `segmentLenghtSum()` есть два параметра `obj_1` и `obj_2`, метод возвращает сумму методов `segmentLenght()`:

```
private int segmentLenghtSum(Segment obj_1,Segment obj_2)
{
    return (segmentLenght(obj_1) + segmentLenght(obj_2));
}
```

Я не всегда имею объект `obj_2` и меня устраивает сокращённый код:

```
private int segmentLenghtSum(Segment obj_1)
{
    return (segmentLenght(obj_1));
}
```

который сам по себе большого смысла не имеет. Можно ли объединить эти два метода в один так, чтобы я мог вводить один или два параметра - в случае введения двух параметров выполнялся бы первый код, в случае одного - второй?

Answer (score 3):

Можно написать такой метод:

```
private int segmentLenghtSum(Segment... params){
    int result = 0;
    for (Object p : params)
        result += segmentLenght(p);
    return result;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Segment obj1, obj2, obj3;
Segment[] objects = new Segment[]{ obj1, obj2, obj3 };
int sum = segmentLenghtSum(obj1, obj2, obj3);
int sum2 = segmentLenghtSum(objects);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java не поддерживает параметры по умолчанию, но вы можете легко проэмулировать их:

```
private int segmentLenghtSum(Segment obj_1)
{
    return segmentLenghtSum(obj_1, null);
}

private int segmentLenghtSum(Segment obj_1, Segment obj_2)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (obj_1 != null)
        result += segmentLenght(obj_1);
    if (obj_2 != null)
        result += segmentLenght(obj_2);
    return result;
}
```

В вашем случае код простой, и можно просто определить два метода, но если код сложный и надо избежать его повторения, делайте как в моём примере.

---

Но всё же, плииииииз! length, а не lenght!

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы!